# How to get spring profile name from java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a separate spring yaml configuration file for each profile.

I need from a `CommandLineRunner` descendant class to read the profile and execute the appropriate script.

Is there a way from java to get the environment profile name?

I have tried this :

```
environment.getActiveProfiles();
```

but it only return an empty string array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Do you have an active profile? when no, it shows nothing.
2. You can also use `environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")` to get active profiles.

Comment: Environment is not a static class in which you can access the methods. It's a class you need to inject as a Spring Bean. Your answer seems not to be right.

Answer (score 0):

This method works fine for me

```
    private static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE";     

    protected void setSpringProfile(ServletContext servletContext) {
     if(null!= System.getenv(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE)){
             profile=System.getenv(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);

     }else if(null!= System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE)){
        profile=System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);

     }else{
        profile="local";
     }

    log.info("***** Profile set  ---> "+ profile);    
    }
```

I am using both System.getenv and System.getProperty because I have observed that in my local system System.getProperty worked but on my docker container System.getenv() worked.

Also, I am defaulting the profile to "local" profile in case nothing has been set.